# Website not showing errors, just 500 page

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php

I have moved some code from development to production and it was not working so I am trying to debug but for the life of me, I cannot get access to the errors to find out what is wrong.

I have tried setting `error_reporting`, `display_errors`, `log_errors` in the Plesk dashboard, `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, CodeIngniter's `index.php` bootstrap, and the function I am calling and I still don't get any errors displayed.

The server is a VPS Red Hat/CentOS setup with Plesk using Apache. The website is built upon CodeIgniter and Doctrine.

Have I missed anything?

Comment: The logs for apache on CentOS are in `/var/log/httpd`

Comment: I think, that you don't want to Apache show the errors. Apache just works. You want to **PHP** to show errors. So you ask wrong question. Therefore all 3 answers are pointless.

Comment: @Bruno9779 there is no /var/log/httpd, just /var/log/apache2

Comment: Well then, did you take a look? If Apache is spitting out 500, the reason will likely be documented in `error_log`.

Comment: Yes, it does not log them.

Comment: Well then, time to find out what Plesk sets the log location too, isn’t it? ;) Just find the virtual host you’re looking for in your Apache config files and take a look. /edit: Ah, you found the logs already. Congrats. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I managed to find more logs deep in Plesk, I have no idea where they are on the filesystem but they pointed me to processes timing out.

Plesk uses Nginx with fastcgi which was timing out and throwing the error through Apache. I increased the timeouts for fastcgi and Nginx which stopped the error showing.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do `which` apache, for plesk apache is in my guess would be in /usr/local/psa/

Comment: which apache2 returns /usr/sbin/apache2. There is no apache, http, httpd

Answer (score 0):

Your are basically asking the wrong question.

Right question is not how to get error message from the Apache, but how to get error message from the CodeIgniter / PHP.

I don't know the CodeIgniter, but similar frameworks works this way: it detects, if it's running on the localhost (development) machine or on the server (production machine). If it's running on development machine, it enables error reporting, otherwise it disables it. So it overwrites your setting wherever it is (`php.ini`, `.htaccess` etc.).

Therefore you should check **how to enable error reporting on production machine in CodeIgniter** or **how to manually set environment to "development" on production machine in CodeIgniter** instead.

Check for example [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages). There is exactly what I have described. Maybe it would be enough to (temporarily) set the environment to "development".

**Don't forget to set it back to "production" when you'll solve your problem!** (or don't forget to disable error reporting depending on what you'll do)

Comment: I have, and that is what I meant by index.php bootstrap. I've written it more clear that is CodeIgniter.

Comment: You have what? Did you set your environment to "development"?

Comment: Yes, and set the error_reporting and such

Comment: You shouldn't have to set error_reporting manually, because it'll be done by CodeIgniter according to current environment. Maybe you have set the encironment just before environment detection, so it was overwritten by CodeIgniter.

Comment: error_reporting is how you set it, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371046/218312

Comment: As I wrote, you shouldn't set error_reporting manually. Rather set the environment to the "development" and let CodeIgniter to set the error_reporting for you.

Comment: I am unaware of the CI version this uses but it is not 2+

Comment: There is really nothing like this in your application's entry point? https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php The only thing I would change in that script is that I would comment line 45 and add "define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');" on line 46. Version 1.x of CodeIgniter have to be very similar.

Answer (score -1):

Restart Apache Server and check

```
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

Comment: I've already restarted Apache a half dozen times.

Comment: I guess, that problem isn't in Apache, but in CodeIgniter application instead. He describes it pretty clearly, but he have chosen wrong question title.